# How to deal with slightly different columns when scanning multiple csv files?

Tags: python-polars

I have a folder containing thousands of csv files which I'd like to scan with PL lazy frame.

Scanning in fact works just fine, but when I try to fetch or collect the df, I get "ShapeError: unable to append to a dataframe of width 63 with a dataframe of width 67".

This means that there are some csv files containing more columns than the others. I checked that there are 4 unique sets of column names. Some csv files contains additional information compared to others.

Ideal outcome would be a dataframe containing all the possible columns and if there are some files that doesn't contain these specific "additional" columns, it would leave those blank.

Current code:

```
df = pl.scan_csv(r"path\*.csv", sep=";", infer_schema_length=0)
df.collect(streaming=True).write_parquet("new_file.parquet")
```

What would be a convenient way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want them stacked diagonally.

I think you may have to do that manually with [`pl.concat`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html#polars.concat) and `how="diagonal"`

```
from pathlib import Path

pl.concat(
   (pl.scan_csv(f) for f in Path().glob("*.csv")),
   how="diagonal"
).collect(streaming=True)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ A    ┆ B    ┆ C    ┆ D    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ null ┆ null ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
│ 5    ┆ 6    ┆ 7    ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Example files used:

```
for f in Path().glob("*.csv"):
    f, f.read_text()
```

```
(PosixPath('1.csv'), 'A,B\n1,2\n')
(PosixPath('2.csv'), 'C,D\n3,4\n')
(PosixPath('3.csv'), 'A,B,C\n5,6,7\n')
```

Comment: Much nicer way than what I was about to do, works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Is diagonal concat on lazyframes new? I feel like I've tried it and I had to do dataframes only.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor A few months: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/5647